# Request header field Authorization despite Access-Control-Allow-Origin being set in express

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, axios

I have made a Vue.js app using Vue-cli and want to consume restricted api from backend.

In order to avoid CORS issue In my app's `server.js` I've set this:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");

  next();
});
```

However, when I make request with authorization header from my Vue.js component:

```
 axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/article', headerConfig)
        .then( res => this.article = res.data)
         .catch(error => console.log(error))            
    }
```

I still get:

```
Failed to load http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/article: Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Appreciate your help to resolve this.

Comment: check this https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html. also there's a `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` in your "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" header is that normal ?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean by 'normal' I send this `headers: {
      Authorization: this.token,
       crossdomain: true
    }` as request axios' `headerConfig`.

Comment: im talking about `app.use()`, check this line : `res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");` you send `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` as header in `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`

Comment: So what should it be? I just copied that from a response on SO to resolve CORS problem.

Comment: did you try what is in https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicitly allow "Authorization" header to be used for cross-origin request with mentioned that for Access-Control-Allow-Headers header:

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Authorization");
```

BTW most of headers you have already included there actually are not needed to be mentioned for CORS since [they are "simple" headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers#Directives) - there is [dedicated list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Simple_header).

And it's related to to headers you are sending explicitly only. 
Say `origin` and `access-control-request-headers` are generated by browser for preflight - until you are not sending them explicitly you also don't need to list them for `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` in response.